# What is document tag in data-config.xml of Solr

Tags: java, xml, solr

I am wirking with solr server. i want to fetch data from MySQL database to solr. the following is the db-data-config.xml:

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" driver="org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.9:3306/angara" user="dev_user" password="ampliflex" />
    <document>
         <entity name="tdiamonds1" query="select UID_PK, ProductUID, name, price,Weight from tdiamonds">

         </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

i want to know what `<document>` tag indicates here, can we give more then one  tag here, if possible please refer me some good example.

Answer (score 0):

`<document>` encapsulates one or more entity elements. You can also specify a name for the given document.